# mysql MariaDB stored procedure error when select from table no data

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am using XAMPP, the database version should be *Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.16-MariaDB*, I have created a simple stored procedure,

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE GetAll()
   BEGIN
   SELECT *  FROM users;
   END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and call it using

```
CALL GetAll();
```

when the table (users) does not have data and I call the stored procedure on phpmyadmin page using statement above, it shows this error:

```
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "ON" at position 25)
SQL query: Edit Edit

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

MySQL said: Documentation

#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

BUT when the table has data, it will not produce an error when I call it.

Does this happen in most databases? What should I do to call the stored procedure even if the table has no data?

Comment: And if you call it from the `mysql cli-terminal`?...I can't believe that there are still people that uses `phpMyAdmin`....

Comment: The stored procedure does not seem to be the problem - it correctly returns no values when users is empty and objects if users does not exist.

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks, it executed successfully through command line. I did not execute any SQL through terminal until now, at least I tried something new today. So phpMyAdmin cant handle empty result? Thanks again.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for comment, the error maybe should be due to I called it from phpMyAdmin like Hackerman said.

Comment: Exactly...you just discovered a new `phpMyAdmin` bug, your stored procedure is good...when in doubt, use the `cli` xD